# is there default filter like ${name | default:'nohting' } in mako template

Tags: python, templates, mako

```
${name | default:'nohting' }
```

if `name` is `False`,I want to use a default value like `nothing` replaced

Answer (score 0):

there is no default filter like that

But you can use your own customized template tags for that

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/